# How to display host, user and port in PostgreSQL

Tags: r, postgresql, pgadmin

I am aiming to use R to connect to a database within PostgreSQL, for which I need to know the database host, port and user.

Do you know how I can find these details within PostgreSQL?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using psql and already logged into the database, you can use the below command to display connection info

`\conninfo`

Answer (score 1):

SELECT current_database() AS database, user AS user;

SHOW port;

If you are using psql(1), you can discover your hostname like this on linux and OSX, respectively:

\echo `hostname`

\echo `scutil --get ComputerName`